# how to call the jquery ui radio button in ajax success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

this is my code i used

```
$('.how-long-u .text-box').keyup(function(){
    var value = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    if (value < 3){
        $.ajax({
            url:'more-address.html',
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data){
                console.log('hello')
                $('.repeated-address').html(data);
                    setTimeout(function(){ $('.radiobutton').buttonset('refresh'); }, 800);                     
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('.repeated-address').html('');
    }
});
```

after the keyup function ajax success is coming correct but radio button is not working

error in console is 
**Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on button prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'widget'**
ca nay one help me pls

Comment: please provide html body code also !!

Comment: Error is telling you you need to initialize the new radio buttons first. You can't refresh something that has never been activated

Comment: thank u for replay.. i done that. its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.radiobutton').buttonset().buttonset('refresh');
```